New Arch gets stuck in a Suspender infinite loop during provider initialization
I upgraded from React Native 0.75.3 -> 0.76.1 and enabled New Arch.
In App.tsx, internal code gets stuck in Suspender state while initializing multiple providers (e.g. Authentication, MMKV, etc.). (useEffect, etc.) Multiple provider parents have Suspender fallback.
export const AuthenticationProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>(null);
  const [authenticating, setAuthenticating] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ AuthenticationProvider: 'init.' });
    if (isLocal) {
      auth().useEmulator(FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_URL);
    }

    const authListener = auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (firebaseUser) => {
      if (!firebaseUser) {
        setUser(null);
      } else {
        setUser(firebaseUser);
      }

      setAuthenticating(false);
    });

    setAuthenticating(false);

    return () => {
      if (authListener) {
        authListener();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  if (authenticating) {
    return <Suspender />;
  }

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuthentication = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useConfig must be used within a AuthenticationProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

Suspender
import type { FC } from 'react';
import { useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';

export type ISuspenderProps = object;

export const Suspender: FC<ISuspenderProps> = () => {
  const resolve = useRef<() => void>();
  const promise = useMemo(
    () =>
      new Promise<void>((res) => {
        resolve.current = res;
      }),
    [],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      resolve.current?.();
    };
  });

  throw promise;
};

I think I'm in an infinite loop in the throw promise part. How do I change the Suspender code to make it work with the new architecture?
